# Работа с датами в ТSQL

Tags: sql-server, sql

```
Готовность: A= (Фактич.отработ.время)/(План.раб.время).
```

Фактически отработанное время можно рассчитать как время, в течение которого ячейка выполняла ЗНП.
Для определения времени, в течение которого ячейка простаивала или выполняла ЗНП, необходимо сделать запрос в базу данных на сервере MS SQL.
Промежуток времени, в течение которого ячейка работала (простаивала) рассчитывать как время от момента ввода статуса (номер ЗНП или номер простоя) до момента ввода следующего статуса или до пересмены (окончания смены). После пересмены следует автоматически обнулять статус ячейки для последующего повторного ввода.
Если во время технологических или обеденного перерывов статусом ячейки был указан номер выполняемой ЗНП, то это время не учитывается как время в работе.
Параметр «Плановое рабочее время» следует считать равным 7,5 часам. Если ячейка ввела статус «Простой по причине окончания смены», то параметр «Плановое рабочее время» следует уменьшить на величину, равную разницу в часах между окончанием рабочей смены и вводом данного статуса.

Не могу вычислить время работы с одной ЗНП в часах, например, если время начала работы 2011-10-13 14:19:45.807 а окончание 2011-10-13 07:20:43.257

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не считайте в часах. Иначе вы для интервала в одну секунду можете получить результат 1 час:

```
select DATEDIFF(HOUR ,'2011-10-14T23:59:59','2011-10-15T00:00:00');
```

Считайте в минутах или секундах, а потом делите на число минут/секунд, например:

```
select DATEDIFF(second ,'2011-10-14T23:59:59','2011-10-15T00:00:00')/3600.;
```

Comment: спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [datediff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms189794.aspx):

```
datediff(hour, датаначала, датаокончания)
```

Comment: ща попробую, спасибо!:)